# Meteor: How to create a user account on the server without sending plain text password over the wire?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am creating an admin interface and the admin needs the ability to create user accounts, pick and change the password.

If I try to call `Account.createUser` on the `Client`, it automatically logs the user in as the new user, which is what I do not want.

An approach that will work but I am afraid might be insecure is:

1. Call a server side Meteor method with the username and password for the new account that the admin has picked.
2. On the server I can use Accounts.createUser to create the new user with password and it will return the new UserId.

But with this approach I am sending the password in plain text over the wire. We could use `https` and `ssl` and I think we will be safe, but is there a more secure way to do this?

Comment: Using `https` is pretty secure. You could try to hash the password in javascript (on the client) before sending it over the wire.

Comment: check this question too https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-secure-is-the-data-sent-via-meteoe-methods-to-the-server/1796

Answer (score 0):

A much better practice which avoids any user knowing any other user's password is to create the account on the server (as you suggested) but don't specify a password, instead let the user pick it later. From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser)

> Call `createUser` with the email option and then call
>   `Accounts.sendEnrollmentEmail`. This will send the user an email with
>   a link to set their initial password.